# BGL : get vertex descriptor with data

Tags: c++, boost, vertex, boost-graph

I want to get the vertex descriptor with the composant of the vertex, like this :

```
struct WayPoint{
std::pair<float, float> pos; // with this composant
};
```

the adjency list :

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<  
    boost::listS,              
    boost::vecS,                
    boost::undirectedS,         
    WayPoint,                   
    WayPointConnection          
> WayPointGraph;
typedef WayPointGraph::vertex_descriptor WayPointID;
typedef WayPointGraph::edge_descriptor   WayPointConnectionID;
```

I built my graph and created all the vertices / edges .... the aim is to apply an astar on the graph.

```
void PathFinding::findMeAPath(std::pair<float, float>begin, std::pair<float, float>end)
{
    std::vector<WayPointID> p(boost::num_vertices(graphe)); 
    std::vector<float>      d(boost::num_vertices(graphe)); 
    WayPointID start = // I want to find the WayPointID with begin
    WayPointID goal = //same with end;
    shortest_path.clear();
    try {
        boost::astar_search
        (
        graphe, 
        start,  
        boost::astar_heuristic<WayPointGraph, float>(), 
        boost::predecessor_map(&p[0]).distance_map(&d[0]).visitor(astar_goal_visitor(goal)).weight_map(boost::get(&WayPointConnection::dist, graphe))
        );

    } catch(found_goal fg) { 

    for(WayPointID v = goal;; v = p[v]) {
        shortest_path.push_front(v);
        if(p[v] == v)
            break;
    }
    }
  }
```

Comment: First, d should use num_edges, not num_vertices. Second, what is the actual question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a function to find a vertex given a position. The graph type that you have defined uses std::vector to store vertices, so the function will have to iterate through it and compare the queried position to each WayPoint. Something like this could do:

```
std::pair<WayPointID, bool> find_vertex(const WayPoint& wp, const WayPointGraph& graph)
{
  for (WayPointID id = 0; id < boost::num_vertices(graph); ++id)
  {
    if (equal(graph[id], wp))
      return std::make_pair(id, true);
  }
  return std::make_pair(0, false);
}
```

Note that the function returns a pair (Id + boolean flag) to indicate whether the search succeeded or not, so you would use it as follows:

```
bool vertex_found;
WayPointID start;
std::tie (start, vertex_found) = find_vertex(begin, graphe);
if (!vertex_found)
  // do something about it
```

Also the function uses the following to compare positions:

```
bool equal(const std::pair<float, float>& p1, const std::pair<float, float>& p2)
{
  const float EPS = 1e-6;
  return (std::fabs(p1.first - p2.first) < EPS &&
          std::fabs(p1.second - p2.second) < EPS);
}
```